# Which software is this?

Tags: windows, web-apps, osx

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this but can anyone tell me the name of this software? I have attached the ss below.

I think it is on mac os but do correct me if I'm wrong.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Airtable](https://www.airtable.com/)
It's like an Excel + DDBB online.